# Nivo Slider - Two Sliders on one web page

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

I copied the code from dev7 studio's example of how to insert two nivo sliders on one web page, but I am unsure how to tweak the individual settings of each slider, such as how to get the first slider to just use arrows, while the second slider only uses bullets. Also how would I adjust the height & width of each slider in terms of location of arrows & bullets.

Here is the style.css:

```
/*=================================*/
   /* Nivo Slider Demo
   /* November 2010
   /* By: Gilbert Pellegrom
   /* http://dev7studios.com
   /*=================================*/

   /*====================*/
   /*=== Reset Styles ===*/
   /*====================*/
   html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-weight:inherit;
    font-style:inherit;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
body {
    line-height:1;
    color:black;
    background:white;
}
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:"";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:"" "";
}
/* HTML5 tags */
header, section, footer,
aside, nav, article, figure {
    display: block;
}

/*===================*/
/*=== Main Styles ===*/
/*===================*/
body {
    font:14px/1.6 Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
    color:#333;
    background:#eee;
}

a, a:visited {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#dev7link {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50px;
    background:url(images/dev7logo.png) no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:67px;
    border:0;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.default #slider {
    margin:100px auto 0 auto;
    width:960px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
    height:310px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
}
.default #slider2 {
    margin:100px auto 0 auto;
    width:280px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
    height:65px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
}
slider-wrapper,
lider-wrapper {
    margin-top:150px;
}

/*====================*/
/*=== Other Styles ===*/
/*====================*/
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Here is the default.css:

```
/*
Skin Name: Nivo Slider Default Theme
Skin URI: http://nivo.dev7studios.com
Skin Type: flexible
Description: The default skin for the Nivo Slider.
Version: 1.0
Author: Gilbert Pellegrom
Author URI: http://dev7studios.com
*/

.default .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
}
.default .nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.default .nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}

.default .nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:70px;
    bottom:25px;
    margin-left:-40px; /* Tweak this to center bullets */
    z-index:300;

}



.default .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:1px;
    float:left;

}








.default .nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}

.default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
.default a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
.default a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}

.default .nivo-caption {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.default .nivo-caption a {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
}
.default .nivo-caption a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use more than one slider on your webpage, you will firstly want to change the `#ID` elements to `.CLASSES`, both in the HTML and in the CSS, as we're creating more than one slider now...

If you are looking at changing each one of your slider's appearances, this would relate to your `HTML` inline-styling and how the skin (default, light, dark etc.) is being output.  Simply change this to the desired skin in your `demo.html` file.  It should look something like this:

> div class="slider-wrapper theme-default"

Now replace "theme-default" with for example, *theme-light*.

To modify the bullets in the default skin slider, you're wanting to play with:

> .default .nivo-controlNav` and .default .nivo-controlNav a {

To modify the arrows in the default skin slider, you're wanting to play with:

> .default .nivo-directionNav a {

Answer (score 0):

ID of each slider should be different and then initialization and settings can be written individually for each one.

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="slide1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="slide2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="slide3.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="slide4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'slideInLeft',          // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 1,                      // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8,                     // For box animations
        boxRows: 4,                     // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500,                 // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000,                // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0,                  // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true,             // Next & Prev navigation
        controlNav: true,               // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false,        // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: true,             // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false,           // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev',               // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next',               // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false,             // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){},     // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){},      // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){},     // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){},        // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){}         // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
</script>
```

The ID part in each jQuery function should be different following the two different IDs you used to identify each slider in the HTML.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
```

Meaning you will have two copies of this code, one per each slider.

Different CSS styles per slider can be attained via these IDs referenced in a CSS file.
Note the .nivoSlider class of the slider container is common in both instances, since it's connected to general styles needed for the slider to work.

Comment: I got solution for my problem from above suggestion, I understood code but I could not understand that where to add this code as I am using CMS DNN 7 for the first time.

Comment: the script part of the code can be added anywhere in the page, provided it's after jQuery and nivo slider references. The html part (the slider itself) has to be added wherever you want the slider to actually show up in the page.